# ES6 how to get source code for filter( ) method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've tried to reproduce the method `filter` so far I have got:

```
function filtre(...[T,x,y]){
let tabPersF = [];
for (let pers of T) {
    if (x(...[pers,y])) {
      tabPersF.push( pers ); 
     }

}
  return tabPersF;
}
```

How about it?.

Comment: It won't work?! It looks ugly?! And whats your question at all?

Comment: Check the [polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) for a proper implementation. Note that the way `filter` is implemented depends on your browser.

Comment: `function` can’t be a parameter name because it’s a keyword and `funcion` is “fortunately” a typo. `array2` is undefined, and there doesn’t exist a `puts` method. Have you looked into the console yet?

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: i've tryed tu create it at my own for training but it seems to not work verry well, cause it doesn't work when for example i work with an array of object with person with sex,age,name i wanna filter female who has age> 19 or something like that

Comment: @JonasW.  What about this?

Comment: @Nico Now you have changed the question itself!

Answer (score 0):

> So I've tried to reproduce the method filter I got this and I know
>   it's not good.

Multiple issues with this code

- `array2` not initialized
- `array2` not an `array` and what is `puts`
- `function` keyword as parameter

Make it

```js
function filter(array, func) {
  let array2 = [];
  for ( var counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++) {       
    if (func(array[counter], counter, array )) {
      array2.push(array[counter]);
    }
  }
  return array2;
}

console.log( filter( [1,2,3], function(s){ return s>1 } ) );

console.log( filter( ["132","322","23433"], function(s){ return s.length>3 } ) );

var arr = [ {name: "asdasd", age: 10}, {name: "asdasd2", age: 20} ];

console.log( filter( arr , function(s){ return s.age>19 } ) );
```

Comment: `func(v)` ... !!

Comment: @JonasW. my bad. Corrected the same.

Comment: @JonasW. `func(v)` works fine. I have given two examples. Why did you mentioned about it earlier?

Comment: it doesn't work when for example i work with an array of object with person with sex,age,name i wanna filter female who has age> 19 or something like that

Comment: @gurvinder i meant `func(v, i, array)`

Comment: @JonasW. ohhh, got it now. And there are other conditions I have not handled like invalid function etc. This was just suppose to be a simple illustration of how `filter` works. Thanks for your inputs though.

Comment: so how a can get the array who contain female with age > 19 using this filter

Comment: @JonasW. yess !! that's it