# Remove an item inside of an array which is inside of another array in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following Structure:

```
export class Contact {
    id: number = 0;
    firstname: string = '';
    lastname: string = '';
    phones: Phone[] = [];
    emails: Email[] = [];
}

export class Email {
    id: number = 0;
    emailType: string = '';
    address: string = '';
}

export class Phone {
    id: number = 0;
    phoneType: string = '';
    number: string = '';
}
```

Now in a component I have an array of `Contact` named `contacts` and a `phone` object.
I want to remove that `phone` object which is in a `phones array` of a `contact` which is inside of a `contacts` array.
Is there a simple way like `filter` or something that can do this easily without going through all `contacts` with a `loop`?

Comment: no there aren't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of another way of doing that and also there is 99.9% chances a function like `filter` would go through a loop

```
removePhone(contacts, phone){
  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
    const currentPhones = contacts[i].phones;
    for (let j = 0; j < currentPhones.length ; j++)
      if (currentPhones[j] === phone)
        return (currentPhones.splice(j, 1));
  }
}
```

or based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47326546/es6-how-to-get-source-code-for-filter-method);

you could do something like

```
function filterAndRemove(array, func) {
  for ( var counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++) {
    for (let i = array[counter].phones.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)  
      if (func(array[counter].phones[i], i, array[counter].phones)) {
        array[counter].phones.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: I was thinking about this problem for a few hours now. Yeah you are right. I'll go this way.

Comment: @AfshinM.Khiabani please mark as answered if that solved your problem I've added another option for you if you wan't you could test it and  add it to the array prototype

Answer (score 1):

While you have to use a loop, that needn't be onerous:

```
for (const contact of contacts) {
    contact.phones = contact.phones.filter(p => p != phone);
}
```

If you need to modify the existing array rather than creating a new one, you can do:

```
for (const contact of contacts) {
  remove(phone, contact.phones);
}
```

where

```
function remove<T>(item: T, array: T[]) {
  const index = array.indexOf(item);
  if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way by using filter:

```
let x = this.contacts.filter(x => x.phones.some(y => y.number == phone.number))[0];
x.phones = x.phones.filter(x => x.id != phone.id);
```

Or by id:

```
let x = this.contacts.filter(x => x.phones.some(y => y.id == phone.id))[0];
x.phones = x.phones.filter(x => x.id != phone.id);
```